# Android List View stops

Tags: android

I am trying to add information in a list view the codes which add these information of list view is in a OnClickListener:

```
else {

                    session2 = new Cart();
                    session2.getItem(im,rat,eqt);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Product.this, Cart.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

and my List view Activity is

public void getItem(String i1,String r1,String e1)
    {
        item1=i1;
        rate=r1;
        quantity=e1;
        createList();
    }


 public void createList()
    {

        System.out.print("Create List entry");

        int qty=Integer.parseInt(quantity);
        int rt=Integer.parseInt(rate);
        int amount=qty*rt;
        String fp=String.valueOf(amount);
        // insert data into the list before setting the adapter
        // otherwise it will generate NullPointerException  - Obviously

        CartItem cr = new CartItem(qty, item1, rt, amount);
        cartItems.add(cr);
        CartItemAdapter cartItemAdapter=new 
        CartItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(),cartItems);
        lvCartItems.setAdapter(cartItemAdapter);

        tvTotalPrice.setText(Constant.CURRENCY + fp);

        if(amount>0){
            c++;
            cartstatus();
        }
        else {
            cartstatus();
        }
    }
```

Can any one please tell me what am I doing wrong I am new to android programming

As the program reaches on the line

```
CartItemAdapter cartItemAdapter=new 
CartItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(),cartItems);
lvCartItems.setAdapter(cartItemAdapter);
```

it stops.

Comment: post your error logcat

Comment: show logcat please

Comment: havent used logcat yet can you tell me how it works

Comment: Are u using Android Studio?

Comment: `it stops` how exactly? does it **crash**?

Comment: yes m using android studio @MohammadArman

Comment: Then Debug your app it will show Logcat more info [https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html]

Comment: @VladMatvienko the emulator stops and asks to close app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: @MohammadArman 

this is my Stack Trace

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:106)
                                                                                       at com.example.rishabmehrotra.foodie.Cart.createList(Cart.java:229)

Comment: Have u solved your problem @Rishab? otherwise u may assign as private CarItemAdapter carItemAdapter = null; before onCreate and before creating object you have to check if (carItemAdapter !=null) then //code here

Comment: I am sorry Guys I was having some internet issues i have solved my problem the problem was in my adapter. thanks for the solutions

Answer (score 0):

May be it will work assign `private CartItemAdapter cartItemAdapter;` 
before `onCreate` method of your Activity then use your code like this `

```
cartItemAdapter=new 
CartItemAdapter(YourActivityName.this,cartItems);
lvCartItems.setAdapter(cartItemAdapter);
```

`